# ActivityNotFoundException using Android Saripaar library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, activitynotfoundexception, saripaar

i've been using this site to fix my problems with android/eclipse. But in this moment im very stuck i searched almost every thread regarding this problem but i cant found a solution.

Its simple i want to move from one activity to other after the validation succeed, using the android saripaar everything was going cool until i got a runtime error in the logcat, the error is

> 07-20 23:10:59.312: E/AndroidRuntime(2562): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.projectcandy/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Please check this specially

> {com.example.projectcandy/android.view.Menu}

com.example.projectcandy its my package and my class is Menu. But why the log cat show me that 'Android.view' ?

What I've done so far?

1) Insert the filter line in the manifest
2)Clean the project
3)Delete the activity from the manifest and add it again using the application nodes > Add etc..
4)Change the way i make the intent. Really i dont know what to do know

Im posting my manifest,MainActivity.java and the "Menu.class" here

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.projectcandy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.projectcandy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".Menu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.projectcandy.Menu" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**On create method from mainactivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    validator = new Validator(this);
    validator.setValidationListener(this);

    usernamereg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernamereg);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    Loginb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Loginb);
    Loginb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           validator.validate();

        }
    });
```

**The onValidationSucceeded Method (From android saripaar library)**

```
    @Override
public void onValidationSucceeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Iniciando sesion...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String user= usernamereg.getText().toString();
    String psw= password.getText().toString();
    if (user.equals("admin") && psw.equals("1234")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class );
        startActivity(i);  
    }
    else {
        Toast t= Toast.makeText(this,"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }

}
```

Maybe im doing something wrong with the parameters of the on click class. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the things is

Menu is an Interface in android of package "android.view". That is why you are getting this error. Try to rename your "Menu" class by any other name, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks you! That was a idiot mistake from me. Well.. newbie things :)

Comment: When you get correct answer. You should upvote that answer so other can get help out of that. This is STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: Done, Thanks for everything